# I observed that the etherum network accepts my transaction when broadcasted with higher nonce, Will this be a threat to the network?

Tags: ethereum, ddos, go-ethereum

I broadcasted transactions with higher nonce, for example: my current nonce is n and i broadcasted transactions from n+2 to n+{larger_number} and i observed that they are being stored in ethereum network, will this be a threat to ether network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node chooses how long to store and forward pending transactions. It can choose to drop a pending transaction at any time. So if the network starts getting slammed, the high-nonce transactions (and low gas price transactions) would start getting dropped.

In practice, most nodes follow fairly simple drop rules. For example, see these `geth` settings:

- `--txpool.lifetime 24h0m0s` which would store pending transactions for up to one day
- `--txpool.globalqueue 8192` which would start dropping transactions when more than 8,192 are pending.